# Mvvm Wpf MaterialDesign Update ViewModel vrom another ViewModel (drawer)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, material-design

Pretty new to MVVM still learning.
I have a problem with the navigation on MVVM. I want to have a drawer that is on all the page so I build the drawer on the MainWindow.xaml. My problem is to be able to bind the CurrentViewModel when I'm not inside the mainwindow.
MainWindow

```
  <Grid>
    <controls:Drawer DataContext="{Binding Navigator}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Navigator.CurrentViewModel}"/>
  </Grid>
```

My Navigator is bind to a Drawer.xaml

```
 <materialDesign:DrawerHost
            IsLeftDrawerOpen="{Binding ElementName=MenuToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}">
                <materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
               <Button Content="Home" Command="{Binding UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand}" CommandParameter="Home"/>
               <Button Content="Admin" Command="{Binding UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand}" CommandParameter="Admin"/>
```

My 2 button work perfectly to change the main View display. So wen I click on Home or Admin, I have the Home or Admin view.

My Goal is to be able when i'm inside the view Admin to go back to another view.
Example: If you are in admin and you create a new User, I want after you click Send you go back to the Home window.
This is the part i'm not able to do.
To Update de view I created this command

```
public class UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        private INavigator _navigator;

        public UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand(INavigator navigator)
        {
            _navigator = navigator;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
                switch(parameter)
                {
                    case "Home":
                        _navigator.CurrentViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
                        break;
                    case "Admin":
                        _navigator.CurrentViewModel = new AdminViewModel();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            
        }
    }
```

And this is the INavigator Interface

```
public interface INavigator
    {
        ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel { get; set; }
        ICommand UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand { get; }
    }
```

I don't know if it's clear enought to get help.
If not let me know what you need more!
Thanks.

EDIT

```
 public class Navigator : INavigator, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentViewModel));
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand => new UpdateCurrentViewModelCommand(this);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you meen? (sorry still a junior :S)

Comment: I think I know what u meen. I edit my first post to put the code for the Navigator class